# XCode Cmake and -fobjc-weak

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake

I have a question regarding a compiling flag **-fobjc-weak**. Currently, I work on the project that is generated using CMake, it uses C++ mainly and some minimal objective-C code to run the app. When studying compiling flags I saw that some of the Cmake target libraries are compiled with **-fobjc-weak** and some does not. This is not the flag that I set in CMake so I assume it is automatically added by XCode. My question is why? Where does it come from and what is the reason and implication of this flag being there? I could have missed something but I cannot seem to find out at which stage this flag gets added.

Another piece of information is that I use a iostoolchain.cmake It is identical to this project tool chain. It has a line like this:

```
    #Check if Xcode generator is used, since that will handle these flags automagically
if(USED_CMAKE_GENERATOR MATCHES "Xcode")
  message(STATUS "Not setting any manual command-line buildflags, since Xcode is selected as generator.")
```

I dont really understand how Xcode end up deciding which flags are being added but that is my suspection to why I am seeing this line added when compiling.

https://github.com/leetal/ios-cmake/blob/master/ios.toolchain.cmake

Cheers!

Comment: Are you developing in C++ is the tag suggest? In this case, `-fobjc-weak` is irrelevant.

Comment: I working in C++ and using some glue objective-C code to run the app. Why would it be irrelevant?